# retrieving http responses from android

Tags: android, http, get

I aldready succed retrieving http values from the web.

However, I still rarely have an idea how I retrieved value from the web.

I have a code. But, without understanding it, what is it for?

So... I want to ask three things to understand my code.

`HTTPGet`, `HTTPClient`, `EntityUtils`.

I am just guessing what HTTPGet does is grabbing http data which made by http coding.

and I am guessing `HTTPClient` is for data encapsulation.

and.. `EntityUtils`? I really dont have a idea. what is entitiy? why do I need this

to get `HTTPresponse` as a string? what does he do?

below is my code.

```
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(tempURL); 
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get); 
    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: Try this link http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html  you can find your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a HTTP request by using GET or POST method, it will send you a response. If there is nothing to send, at least the server sends the [status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). As an example 200 status code stands for "OK".

So, by using EntityUtils, or

```
InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

will give you the response in a human readable format. If you have send a request to a PHP page you will echo values as response. These are two examples for [GET](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/20/handling-http-get-method-in-android/) and [POST](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/handling-http-post-method-in-android/) to understand with full Android source code and PHP source code.

Answer (score 0):

from package of **org.apache.http.util**

```
EntityUtils.toString();
```

is the method which allow the String Conversion of http response's entity into encoded format (encoding information from the server).

Comment: For more info look at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29